# Error in array [Android]

Tags: android, arrays, position, int

i get a error when i have the int [poition] in the textdescription1.setText()

the error i get is (The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int)
i don't why i get that error becuse it's an array and [position] is a int.

Does anyone know why i get this error and how to fix it?

sorry for my bad english :P
thx

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {      
        txtdescription1.setText(R.array.banan[position]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get your array in the following method:

```
int[] banan_arr = R.getIntArray(R.array.banan);
```

if banan is of String type then change accordingly